# Whatsapp message to number not on address book

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, whatsapp

on Whatsapp faq we read that we can send a message to a number not in phone address book:

```
<ion-button href="https://wa.me/123456789">Chat</ion-button>
```

On click Whatsapp starts saying that the number is not in address book...

Why?

Thank you

[whatsapp direct chat](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add country code as well

```
<ion-button href="https://wa.me/911234567892">Chat</ion-button>
```

try with valid number.